# Issue with ViewHolder pattern

Tags: android, performance

So I'm using a well known ViewHolder pattern in my app. My ViewHolder:

```
protected static class ViewHolder{
    final ImageView itemImage;
    final TextView txtName;
    final TextView txtTitle;
    final WebView webView;

    public ViewHolder (final ImageView itemImage,  final TextView txtName, final TextView txtTitle, final WebView webView){
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
        this.txtName = txtName;
        this.txtTitle = txtTitle;
        this.webView = webView;
    }

    public ViewHolder (View convertView){
        itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_item_icon);
        txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_item_name);
        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_item_title);
        webView = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_webView);
    }
}
```

So everything works fine if I use it with the 1st constructor like:

```
...
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

                    final Searchable searchResultsItem = searchResults.get(position);

                    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                    if (convertView==null){
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null);

                        final ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_item_icon);
                        final TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_item_name);
                        final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_item_title);
                        final WebView webView = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_webView);
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemImage, txtName, txtTitle, webView);

                        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                    }else
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

                    viewHolder.webView.setFocusable(false);
    ...
```

but fails if I try to use the 2nd constructor:

```
...
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

                    final Searchable searchResultsItem = searchResults.get(position);

                    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                    if (convertView==null){
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null);

                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                    }else
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

                    viewHolder.webView.setFocusable(false);
    ...
```

It crashes with NPE at line `viewHolder.webView.setFocusable(false)`. When I try to debug it says that created ViewHolder instance has all fields null. Why this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids seems are different, is that intentional?
`final WebView webView = (WebView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_webView);
R.id.search_webView`  (This one works)

and

`webView = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_webView);

R.id.fav_webView` (this one does not work)

Comment: OMG, thank you. Its all about my stupid copypaste :) Code looks very similar so I didn't notice that.

Comment: It is kinda interesting that you are using a webview in each instance of ListViewItem. How stable is the app with it?

Comment: Well I can't say for sure. At least I didn't face any bug related to WebView. I didn't like the idea with webviews in ListView items but I cant change it (cuz API sends me html-pages as info to display). What I can say for sure that this schema produce lags on ListView scrolling and also its a way too slow in terms of refreshing when scrolling ListView.

Comment: exactly! That is the performance issue there with webviews in listview.